# Reduce space of index area between subcaptions

Tags: spacing, captions, subcaption

I'm inserting 2 rows of images with `\subcaptionbox` but the vertical space between them remains, which is originally occupied by index of first column images.

How could I reduce the space of this area?

[image]

My code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{position=b}
    \centering
    \caption{my-images}
    \label{fig:images}

    \subcaptionbox*{
        \label{img-0}}
    {\includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{img-0.jpg}}\hspace{0.5em}
    \subcaptionbox*{
        \label{img-1}}
    {\includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{img-1.jpg}}\hspace{0.5em}
    \subcaptionbox*{
        \label{img-2}}
    {\includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{img-2.jpg}}

    \subcaptionbox{
        \label{img-10}}
    {\includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{img-0.jpg}}\hspace{0.5em}
    \subcaptionbox{
        \label{img-11}}
    {\includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{img-1.jpg}}\hspace{0.5em}
    \subcaptionbox{
        \label{img-12}}
    {\includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{img-2.jpg}}

\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would place each of the sub-figures' stack of elements in a `tabular`. This allows you to easily control the gap using `\\[<len>]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{position=b}
  \centering
  \caption{my-images}\label{fig:images}

  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% Remove column gap in tabular
  \subcaptionbox{\label{img-0}}{%
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      \includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{img-00.jpg} \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
      \includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{img-10.jpg}
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hspace{0.5em}%
  \subcaptionbox{\label{img-1}}{%
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      \includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{img-01.jpg} \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
      \includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{img-11.jpg}
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hspace{0.5em}%
  \subcaptionbox{\label{img-2}}{%
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      \includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{img-02.jpg} \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
      \includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{img-12.jpg}
    \end{tabular}}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The above suggestion is based on the fact that a `\subcaptionbox*` with a `\label` seems redundant. However, if you do wish to retain such layout, you can insert a negative vertical space to reduce the gap between the two rows:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{position=b}
  \centering
  \caption{my-images}\label{fig:images}

  \subcaptionbox*{.}{..}%
  \hspace{0.5em}%
  \subcaptionbox*{.}{..}%
  \hspace{0.5em}%
  \subcaptionbox*{.}{..}%

  \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}

  \subcaptionbox{\label{.}}{..}%
  \hspace{0.5em}%
  \subcaptionbox{\label{.}}{..}%
  \hspace{0.5em}%
  \subcaptionbox{\label{.}}{..}%  
\end{figure}
```